# HTML table: remove space between two tr

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I remove space between the 1st `tr` and 2nd `tr`? I have to use image and can't use `border` property.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" height="40" style="padding-left:30px;padding-bottom:0px;border-collapse: collapse;">

      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td valign="middle" height="40" align="center" style="color: #FFFFFF;display: block;padding-left: 55px;padding-right: 55px;background-color:#EE163A;">
              <span class="event_register" style="color: #FFFFFF;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;font-size: 14px;line-height: 40px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'proxima_novasemibold', Arial, sans-serif;"
              target="_blank">Day 1</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height:0px;border-collapse: collapse;">
      <img src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/arrow.png" width="10" height="10" style="padding-left:100px; vertical-align:top; " valign="top" align="top">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `cellspacing="0"` and `cellpadding="0"` to the top most table. Also there is a padding in `td` which needs to be set to `0`. If you want the down arrow to stick to the top div then you would have to give `margin-top:-2px` as there is an space in the image itself

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" height="40" style="padding-left:30px;padding-bottom:0px;border-collapse: collapse;">

      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td valign="middle" height="40" align="center" style="color: #FFFFFF;display: block;padding-left: 55px;padding-right: 55px;background-color:#EE163A;">
              <span class="event_register" style="color: #FFFFFF;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;font-size: 14px;line-height: 40px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'proxima_novasemibold', Arial, sans-serif;"
              target="_blank">Day 1</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height:0px;border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0;">
      
      <span style="padding-left:100px; vertical-align:top; background:url(http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/arrow.png) 100px -2px no-repeat;    background-size: contain; width: 10px; height: 10px; display: block;" valign="top" align="top">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can i do it without `margin` ? As I am making HTML Emailer , so in outlook, `margin` is not supported.

Comment: There are couple of options I could think of. 1) The easiest and most reliable would be to edit the image and remove the space at top.
2) Use the image as a background image and set the position.

Comment: i can work on 1st one. as i said i am making html emailer , so `background-image` and `position` will not be supported by Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

use `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">` for the top level table as well

additionally the image your using is also having blank are above arrow ho need to crop that..

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" height="40" style="padding-left:30px;padding-bottom:0px;border-collapse: collapse;">

      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td valign="middle" height="40" align="center" style="color: #FFFFFF;display: block;padding-left: 55px;padding-right: 55px;background-color:#EE163A;">
              <span class="event_register" style="color: #FFFFFF;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;font-size: 14px;line-height: 40px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'proxima_novasemibold', Arial, sans-serif;"
              target="_blank">Day 1</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height:0px;border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0;">
      <img width="10" align="top" height="10" valign="top" style="padding-left: 100px; vertical-align: top; margin-top: -2px;" src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/arrow.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```